# How to Stop Subscribbed router event In Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, router

In-app Navigation cant be stopped without using Guard???

## Below is my Sample Code

```
 constructor(
      private XXXXXService: XXXXXService
  ) {
    this.XXXX.XX_amount = 0;

    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          //do something on start activity
          console.log("event instanceof NavigationStart",this.router.events, event)
          if(this.invoiceForm.dirty){ 
            if(window.confirm("WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save these changes, or OK to lose these changes."))
            { 
            const currentRoute = this.router.routerState;
            console.log("pressed CANCEL NOT OK", this.router.routerState,currentRoute.snapshot.url);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(currentRoute.snapshot.url, { skipLocationChange: false });
          }
          else
          {
            const currentRoute = this.router.routerState;
            // This is some CODE Im Trying,please ignore this
               //event.preventDefault()
            console.log("pressed CANCEL NOT OK", this.router.routerState,currentRoute.snapshot.url);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(currentRoute.snapshot.url, { skipLocationChange: true });
          }
        }
          
      if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          // Handle error
          console.error(event.error);
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          //do something on end activity
          console.log("event instanceof NavigationEnd")
      }
    }
    });
  }

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (this.hasUnsavedData()) {
        $event.returnValue =true;
    }
}
hasUnsavedData()
{
  return !this.XXXXForm.dirty
}
```

## ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.location.getState());

Irrespective of Windown Confirm result, the page still navigates to differrent page. In-app Navigation cant be stopped.

Comment: Show the surrounding code. It seems you trigger the confirm when navigation is already in process..

Comment: @MikeOne Surrounding Code is, i used I used below code Inside my constructor and and **This Code for help Prevent closing and Refresh issue.

**To prevent tab/browser close and reload confirm
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (this.hasUnsavedData()) {
        $event.returnValue =true;
    }
}
hasUnsavedData()
{
  return !this.SomeFORM.dirty
}

and my Original code i re-edited in the same Question.

Comment: @MikeOne Yes i trigger Confirm During Navigation only as because my requirement is ONLY, while navigating away Check for Form Dirty and if Allow navigate else, Fill form and then Navigate

Answer (score 0):

Make the action that changes the route, subject to a form check. I use this in a button on-click event that takes the visitor to another page.

Trying something like this.

```
onBack(): void {
 if (this.checkForm()) {
    // navigate elsewhere
 }
}

checkForm(): boolean {
   if (this.customerForm.touched) {
       return confirm(`Navigate away and lose all your changes?`);
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Tons for Fast response but, Route Change Action, is already subjected to router.event.subscribe() event and irrespective of confirm msg response, it redirects to new page.

Comment: Oh I see. It wasn't clear from your initial description. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve? Can you not use a route guard? Am I missing something?